# Приложение вылетает из эмулятора

Tags: java, android-studio, аудио, android-on-click

Написал такой код в Android studio, где издается звук при нажатии на картинку, но при клике на изображение в эмуляторе приложение вылетает. Смотрел логи, но ничего путного в интернете по этому поводу не нашел. Буду крайне рад за помощь

```
package com.example.project_1; 
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

private ImageView img1, img2;
private MediaPlayer sound1, sound2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);

    sound1=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sn1);
    sound2=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sn2);

    imageClick();
}

public void imageClick() {
    img1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SoundPlay(sound1);
                }
            }
    );

    img2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SoundPlay(sound2);
                }
            }
    );
}

public void SoundPlay(MediaPlayer allsounds) {
    allsounds.start();
}

}
```

а вот и часть лога из error, ибо строк слишком(!) много:

```
2019-06-01 13:58:26.684 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 13:59:08.565 1869-1975/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.as, application is not in focus neither is the IntelligeService for user 0
2019-06-01 13:59:26.696 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 13:59:26.697 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:00:26.718 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:00:26.719 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:01:26.737 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:01:26.737 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:02:26.752 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:02:26.752 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:03:26.760 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:03:26.761 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 13:59:13.317 1869-1975/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.as, application is not in focus neither is the     IntelligeService for user 0
2019-06-01 14:03:44.845 12244-12244/? E/id.partnersetu: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-06-01 14:03:44.855 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:04:18.086 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:04:26.761 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:04:26.761 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:05:26.820 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:05:26.820 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:05:41.570 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:05:41.584 12270-12270/? E/droid.apps.tip: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-06-01 14:05:41.887 12270-12270/? E/tips-smartspace-binder: PSS session is null
2019-06-01 14:06:01.953 12294-12294/? E/.android.diale: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-06-01 14:06:02.007 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:06:17.658 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:06:26.866 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:06:26.866 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:06:37.037 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:06:37.044 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:06:37.150 12331-12331/? E/android.youtub: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-06-01 14:06:38.527 12331-12360/? E/GEL_DELAYED_EVENT_DEBUG: Failed delayed event dispatch, no dispatchers.
2019-06-01 14:06:40.082 1617-12458/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100,<unspecified>/0)
2019-06-01 14:07:10.825 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:07:10.841 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:07:26.874 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
 2019-06-01 14:07:26.875 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:07:43.551 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:07:53.566 1869-1975/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.as, application is not in focus neither is the  IntelligeService for user 0
2019-06-01 14:08:26.881 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:08:26.882 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:09:26.895 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:09:26.895 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:10:26.941 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:10:26.941 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:11:10.114 1869-1887/? E/AppIdleHistory: Error writing app idle file for user 0
2019-06-01 14:11:26.953 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:11:26.954 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:11:42.263 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:11:42.270 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:11:42.270 1869-1887/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-01 14:12:26.956 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-01 14:12:26.956 1732-1732/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

вы немного не так сделали. попробуйте этот код. возможно, я тоже где-то ошибся (спешу и убегаю), но направление мысли 100% верное.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView img1, img2;
    private MediaPlayer player; // это сам плеер
    int sound1, sound2; // это ваши муз.файлы

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img1 = findViewById(R.id.image1);
        img2 = findViewById(R.id.image2);

        sound1 = R.raw.sn1;
        sound2 = R.raw.sn2;

        imageClick();
    }


    public void imageClick() {
        img1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SoundPlay(sound1);
                    }
                }
        );

        img2.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SoundPlay(sound2);
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    public void SoundPlay(int allsounds) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, allsounds);
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, интересный вариант, но даже после этого в логах идет вот это:

Comment: @user339879 я отредактировал ответ заново. попробуйте так.

Comment: Благодарю за уделенное вами время, но, вероятнее всего, проблема кроется еще и в забагованной версии. Не могли бы вы сказать номер вашей версии и, если не трудно, отправить архивом это "задание".
(я проверил сдк менеджер и докачал все что нужно, но если даже ваш архив не запустится, то проблема уж точно не в коде)

Comment: @user339879 у меня  IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (если я правильно понял, что это версия). да, завтра сделаю *zip, а то я уже удалил проект.

Comment: @user339879 https://yadi.sk/d/-l1SK4tEXeQjgw

Comment: Мне не хватит слов, чтобы описать вам мою благодарность! 
Хоть даже и ваш код и не запустился, я смог понять, что проблема кроется в чем-то ином. Но после починки это проблемы, я уверен, что ваша работа будет функционировать.
Огромное вам спасибо :)
Кстати, как вы считаете: может ли стать причиной многочисленных проблем иной вирус?

Comment: @user339879 без понятия. я бы советовал все удалить через инсталяторы, почистить реестр и переустановить все. я когда настраивал свою Idea на Android мучался 2 дня со всеми эмуляторами, SDK и прочими инструмом.